# Adding CSS To iframe in Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, shopify

I am Adding Css to the iframe in shopify . but its not working..
Here is my code .

```js
<script>
 $('#twitter-widget-0').load(function() {
  var css = '<style type="text/css"> body {background: white};</style>';
  $('#twitter-widget-0').contents().find("head").append(css);
});
    </script>
```

Comment: use .css function . $('#twitter-widget-0').contents().find("head").css('background-color','white')

Comment: its still not working. Do you have another alternative ?

Comment: are you sure that your jquery selectors are correct? is it pointing to correct DOM?

Comment: quite sure, actually I am trying to change the style of <p> tag in the iframe. if you have an other code. can you help me ?

Comment: You cannot inject html into an iframe like this. It is not allowed due to security concerns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code. If your DOM is proper.

```
<script>
 $('#twitter-widget-0').load(function() {
  var css = '<style type="text/css"> body {background: white}</style>';
  $('#twitter-widget-0').contents().find("head").append(css);
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer

```
  <script>$(document).ready(function(){$('#twitter-widget-0').load(function() {var css = '<style type="text/css"> body {background: white;}</style>';$('#twitter-widget-0').contents().find("head").append(css);}); });
```